# Firestore onSnapshot of nested collection inside document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a chat with Firebase->firestore with web, and therefore I am trying to make it live with onSnapshot so users will be able to get a message if they have the chat open.

I have structured the noSQL database like this:

I have a collection named Chats, in that collection I have documents, the names of the documents represent a relationship hash between the 2 users which is also stored in my SQL database, My thought is I will use this as the identifier.

[image]

In each document, there is a **collection** named 'conversations' which will contain all of the chats between the two users.

[image]

If I listen on a document that has a specific id inside the first collection 'chats', I will get a log in my console if I change a field like 'timestamp', so that part works.

```
db.collection('chats').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', '#randomHASH').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    console.log('CHANGES');
    console.log(changes);

    changes.forEach(change => {
        console.log(change.doc.data());
    })
});
```

But how do I listen for the collection 'conversations' inside of the targeted document?
I would like to get a log every time a new document has been added or edited inside the targeted document

I tried, but that does not seem to be the trick.

```
db.collection('chats').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', '#randomHASH').collection('conversations').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    console.log('CHANGES');
    console.log(changes);

    changes.forEach(change => {
        console.log(change.doc.data());
    })
});
```

And this is how I initiate Firebase

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.1.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.1.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "myapp-xxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "myapp-xxxxx",
    storageBucket: "myapp-xxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "1:xxxxx:web:xxxx",
    measurementId: "x-xxxxxx"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
  const db = firebase.firestore();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply do:

```
db.collection('chats').doc('#randomHASH').collection('conversations').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {...});
```

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html), "A `DocumentReference` can also be used to create a `CollectionReference` to a subcollection."

Actually, you can chain the [`collection()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#collection) and [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) methods, as many time as needed, to get a reference to any doc or (sub-)(sub-)(...)collection

---

Note that, similarly, in the first case you can do:

```
db.collection('chats').doc('#randomHASH').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {...});
```

---

*Now, why is your code working in the first case and not in the second case?*

In the first case, by doing `db.collection('chats').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', '#randomHASH')` you define a [`query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query.html) which does have an `onSnapshot()` method.

But in the second case you call a `collection()` method on the same `query`, while a `query` does not have such a method.